# Angular 6 or 5 Performance issue on button click

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently working on an Angular 6 application. I'm facing a performance issue with a simple component: Button Click, increment or decrement a counter variable.

The **counter.component.html** looks like that:

```
<div>Count: <strong>{{ currentCnt }}</strong></div>

<button (click)="manageCounter()"> + </button>
```

the **counter.component.ts** looks like that:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html'
})
export class CounterComponent {
  public currentCnt = 0;

  public manageCounter() {
    this.currentCount++;
  }
}
```

This is a very basic example. The counter component is used in a bigger application together with several other components.

The problem is, when I quickly click the button several times on a smartphone or if I change the Chrome settings=>Performance to CPU: Slowdown, and click the button several times in a row, the Counter increments or decrements very slowly, with a delay of a few milliseconds.

I'm wondering, maybe this behaviour is due to the event bubbeling. 
Perhaps there is a better way to register the events differently?

Do you know how to solve such a performance issue in Angular 6 or 5?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can try `(click)="manageCounter(); $event.stopPropagation();"` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I just up-converted a app from 5 and I'm having the same issue.  Basically about 1.5 seconds of JavaScript is running from event (click) thru zone.js.  Stopping propagation didn't have much effect on a larger view.  So maybe need a different solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can try with stopping propagation as:

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="manageCounter($event)"> + </button>
```

**component.ts**

```
public manageCounter($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    this.currentCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to follow up with a possibility.  If you are in dev-mode you may be getting more lag off zone.js.  I just realized all my problems are when I'm running `ng serve --open` .. but when I run my buildprod task, the prod version is peppy.

`ng build --target=production --environment=prod` give that a shot.

Edit: I had to switch to `ng build --prod` in Angular 6 too.